# Use Remind101 in iOS app

Tags: ios

Is it possible to embed Remind101 within another app?  I have googled and haven't had any luck finding any SDKs but thought maybe some here may have had some success with perhaps deeply buried github projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Natalie from Remind. We don't currently have a public API / SDK available, but are considering offering something in the future. Definitely shoot us an email at contact@remind.com and we'll follow up with you once it's possible to interface with our API, etc. Excited to hear from you!  (Note: We do have a widget available that streams a user's sent Remind messages to his/her website or class page.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be possible to interface with Remind, but it's not entirely clear.  There is a [ruby gem for communicating with a Remind API](https://rubygems.org/gems/remind101/) (JSON, it seems), but I am unable to find documentation for the API itself.  In addition, the ruby gem project seems to have been removed from [Remind's Github account](https://github.com/remind101), so take that as you will.  You might want to reach out to Remind support to ask if it is still possible to communicate with Remind in this way.

If you do wish to attempt communication via the API, I would begin by playing with the Remind101 gem in ruby on your desktop OS X machine first.  If you're able to successfully communicate, then you can set about building a native iOS SDK to make the same network calls.

Good luck!